# Showing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = e$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = e$

I got this limit while solving another problem. Usually limits that look like this can be easily handled by factoring expressions, but this limit has addition inside the parenthesis which confuses me. How can this limit be solved? No l'Hopitals, thank you :)

Comment: You should use the well known limit $(1+(1/n))^n\to e$ and the not so famous lemma which says that if $n(a_n-1)\to 0$  then $a_n^n\to 1$. Now choose $a_n=(1+n^{-1}+n^{-2})/(1+n^{-1})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well note $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$. And you know $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$ We now write your expression as $$\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{n+1} \times \frac{n+1}{n}}=e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}}=e$$

Comment: Oh it was that simple! Thank you xD

Answer (score 3):

$(1+\frac 1 n)^{n} \leq (1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n}$. Now $(1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n}=e^{n\log(1+\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {n^{2}})}$ and you can use the inequality $\log(1+x) \leq x$ ($x>0$) to get the upper bound $e^{1+\frac 1 n}$. Now use squeeze theorem to complete the proof.

Comment: Kavi.Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

For any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
$$
1+\frac1n<1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\leq 1+\frac{1+\varepsilon}{n}
$$
for all $n$ large enough, so
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n< \left(1+\frac{1+\varepsilon}{n}\right)^n.
$$
Taking limit $n\to\infty$, we have
$$
e\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\leq e^{1+\varepsilon}.
$$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=e.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would take logarithms and consider
$$\ln\left[\left(1+\frac1 n+\frac 1{n^2}\right)^n\right]
=n\ln\left(1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}\right)=n\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\left(\frac1 n+\frac 1{n^2}\right)^k.$$
In this sum, apart from the first term, the sum of the remaining terms is $O(1/n^2)$, so the sum is
$$n\left(\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+nO(1/n)=1+O(1/n)\to1.$$
As its logarithm tends to $1$, the original expression tends to $e$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to think with the definition: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n}=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{(1+ t)^{\frac{1}{t}}}=e$$

Therefore , $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1+ \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})^n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1+ \frac{n+1}{n^2})^n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1+ \frac{n+1}{n^2})^{
\frac{n^2}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n^2}\cdot n}}=e^1=e$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for $1^\infty$ form. 
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=\mathrm{e}^{\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)g(x)}$$
such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$.
Now using the formula here gives,
$$L=\mathrm{e}^{\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n}=\mathrm{e}$$

Comment: @Bernard I was about to complete that edit :)

Comment: @Ak19: There's still something to be edited :)

Comment: Is it $$(1+\frac{1}{n})\color{blue}{^n}$$? @Bernard

Comment: Yes, and $e$, which should be $\mathrm e$ (it is a constant).

Comment: Yeah! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also with the limit of the log,  but doing some asymptotic analysis:
$$n\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)=n\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n+o\bigl(\frac1n\bigr)\Bigr)=n\Bigl(\frac1n+o\bigl(\frac1n\bigr)\Bigr)=1+o(1). $$